# How to throw an error using trigger, if an opportunity already having a quote and agreement, and agreement status = in Effect?

Tags: trigger, quote, cpq

when I create a quote (using a button on opportunity object), I want to throw an error when Status Category = 'in effect' and there already exists a primary quote i.e   Primary Quote Is Checked.
Status Category is a picklist field in Agreement Object and Primary Quote is a checkbox in Quote object.

I am doing it using a trigger(Cannot be done using a VR)
I have attached an image which shows the relationship b/w quote, agreement and opportunity object.
I have written the below code, but it is not working

```
trigger trigger1 on SBQQ__Quote__c (before insert){
    Set<id> parentIds = new Set<id>();
     for(SBQQ__Quote__c q: Trigger.new){
         parentIds.add(q.SBQQ__Opportunity2__c);
       }   
   system.debug('>>>>>>'+parentIds);
    Map<Id,Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c> parentMap = new Map<Id,Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c>();
     parentMap.putAll([select id,Apttus__Status_Category__c  from Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c where Apttus__Status_Category__c = 'In Effect' and  Apttus__Related_Opportunity__c in :parentIds ]);
    system.debug('gargi parentMap'+parentMap);
    for (SBQQ__Quote__c q : Trigger.new){
    system.debug('>>>>>>>q'+q);
         if((q.SBQQ__Primary__c==true) && parentMap.containsKey(q.SBQQ__Opportunity2__c)!= null) {
         system.debug('gargi inside if');
         system.debug('>>>>>>>>>>q.SBQQ__Opportunity2__c' +q.SBQQ__Opportunity2__c);
           q.addError('Primary quote cannot be changed when quote/agreement has an active eSignature');
         }
     }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is your question? Please [edit] your post, and see [ask] for what we look for in a question.

Comment: @DavidReed I have updated now. I hope it is understandable now.

Comment: Your post needs to contain _a question_. You have only provided us with your objective statement and a block of code: the community does not know what _problem_ you have that you're asking for help with. However, in this case, it's fairly easy to see what the issue is and I have linked another question with the same solution.

Answer (score -1):

finally, I was able to achieve the requirement with the help of below trigger

```
 trigger trigger1 on SBQQ__Quote__c (before insert){
    Set<id> parentIds = new Set<id>();
     for(SBQQ__Quote__c q: Trigger.new){
         parentIds.add(q.SBQQ__Opportunity2__c);
       }   
    Map<Id,Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c> parentMap = new Map<Id,Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c>();
     parentMap.putAll([select id,Apttus__Status_Category__c  from Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c where Apttus__Status_Category__c = 'In Effect' and  Apttus__Related_Opportunity__c in :parentIds ]);
    for (SBQQ__Quote__c q : Trigger.new){
    if((q.SBQQ__Primary__c==true) && parentMap.size()>0) {    
      q.addError('Primary quote cannot be changed when quote/agreement has an active eSignature');
         }
     }

}
```

Comment: Answer posts should clarify the problem and the solution, not just dump code. Answers that consist exclusively of code pastes are of limited value to the rest of the community. Please take a look at [answer] and [edit] this post to provide explanation.